# How to create a php bi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i am new to php and i must complete an assignment for a php course i'm doing but i am having some trouble understanding it.

Basically i must create a program with the following output using loops and strings :

```
a 00000000
b 00000000
c 00000X00
d 00000000
e 00000000
f 000X0000
g 00000000
h 00000X00
  12345678
```

"where the user enters a bi-dimensional string at the beginning. Based on this string (coordinates) draw "x" on the table."

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: `$x['f'][4] = 'X';` Beyond that, the usual holds: do your own homework. Part of learning is having to figure things out on your own, not just running for help.

Comment: are the coordinates in A1, G7 format or 1A, 7G?

Comment: I think they are a1 and g7.

Comment: so 'YX' as opposed to 'XY', strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you would like something like [this](http://danielabbey.co.uk/so/15935853/).

source code:

```
        <?php
            $Y = range('a', 'h');
            $X = range(1, 8);
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
            <div id="in">Coord X: <input type="number" min="1" max="8" name="x" value="<?php echo $X[array_rand($X)]; ?>"></div>
            <div id="in">Coord Y: <input type="text" name="y" value="<?php echo $Y[array_rand($Y)]; ?>"></div>
            <br /><input id="subm" type="submit" value="DRAW!">
            <input name="reset" id="reset" type="submit" value="reset">
        </form>
        <table>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td></td><?php foreach($X as $x) echo "<td><strong>$x</strong></td>"; ?>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tr>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['reset']))
                    {
                        session_destroy();
                        header('Location: thisPage.php');
                    }
                    $coords = !empty($_GET) ? $_GET['x'].$_GET['y'] : NULL;
                    $_SESSION['coords'][] = $coords;
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($Y); $i++)
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td><strong>$Y[$i]</strong></td>";
                        for($j = 0; $j < count($Y); $j++)
                        {
                            if(isset($_GET) && in_array($X[$j].$Y[$i], $_SESSION['coords']))
                            {
                                echo '<td id="ex"><strong>X</strong></td>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<td>0</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what i want. Any chance of getting access to the php file ? Thank you.

Comment: great, I shall edit my post later with the source code

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Marc B that you need to do your own homework. You can learn about PHP arrays and how to use them on the php.net site: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php and also here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: Yep, you are certainly right. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are automated ways of generating the multi-array using loops (While, For, Foreach) but you can figure those out. Here is a manual way:

```
 $array = array('a'=>array(1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,),'b'=>array(1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,));
```

Then you need to build an html input and receive the input with $_GET or $_POST

Use that input to decide where to do what Marc B said:

```
 $array[$y][$x] = 'X';
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you i will research it further.